# Creating python subclass issue

Tags: python, class, subclass

I'm having some trouble with class inheritance in Python 3.1x that I am hoping to get some help with. I have a  class called `ClassA` and I am trying to create another class called `ClassB` that inherits from `ClassA`. Here is the code I've written:

```
from myfile import ClassA

class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__()
```

When I try to create an instance of `ClassB` I get this error:

```
>>> x = ClassB()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ClassB' is not defined
```

Which is my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not referring to [what you've imported](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

```
>>> import SomeModule
>>> x = SomeModule.ClassB()
```